# How to iterate through options of selector with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very large project and have narrowed down my selector to:

```
//The $component is found from various other vars using .find to this point
var $selector = $Component.find('[class="multiselect-container"]');
```

and I'm trying to use the .each function to iterate through all of the values and their strings. I've tried a few different things over the past hour or so to no avail.

the selector has multiple `<li class="option">` tags

and each option contains `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` which holds `<label class="radio checkbox-label">` which holds `<input type="radio" value="10">` and " 10"

I need to get the value and the string (because they are different at times). If I can get that done, I believe putting each set of data into a 2d array should be easy.

I've tried reading other questions about this, but nothing explains how to use .each once you've already found an element that you want to iterate through.

Comment: It would be better to show your HTML instead of trying to describe it in words.

Comment: You should also show the code you attempted, not just say "I'm trying to use the .each function". How can we explain what you're doing wrong, so you learn from the mistake, if you don't show your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this seems like it should work:

```
var array = [];
$selector.find("label.radio").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input:radio").val();
    var string = $(this).text();
    array.push({ string: string, value: value });
});
```

BTW, don't use `[class=classname]` in a selector, use `.classname`. Your selector won't work if the element has multiple classes and you just want to match one of them, it will try to match the entire `class` attribute literally.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Hopefully this will help someone out with a similar problem.

Comment: You should clarify the question as I said above, so that they'll know if their setup is problem.

Answer (score 0):

1st, since you have the class name, query for that with $(".multiselect-container") instead.

You can retrieve the values from the child dom elements. Simply grab the innerText or the label text.

```
$Component.find('.multiselect-container').each(function(){
    var value = $("input", this).val();
    var label = $("label", this).text();
    var text = input.innerText;
    //  text and label might be the same value
});
```

Or you can filter it to the checked radio buttons

```
$Component.find('.multiselect-container input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
   var value = this.value;
   var label = $(this).closest("label").text();
   // var li = $(this).closest("li")
   // same as above
});
```